# Replace Null with 0's in Dynamic Pivot Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql

I am receiving null values. How could I replace the null values with 0's instead? I've tried the isNull function in the pivot and in the select, but it doesn't seem to update. TY

```
SET @query ='SELECT * FROM(SELECT
      petstoreemployee.employeefirstname as employeefirstname
      ,sum(petID.breed) as breeds
      ,Format(date, ''MMMM-yyyy'') as Month

FROM
      petID, petstoreemployee
WHERE
      petID.petstoreemployeeID=petstoreemployee.petstoreemployeeID and
      petID.ProjectedPrjID=1
      and
      (petID.date >= ''2017-01-01 00:00:00:000'' AND petID.date <= 
''2017-12-31 00:00:00:000'')
  group by petstoreemployee.employeefirstname, Format(date,''yyyy'')

)
as d
PIVOT(
avg(breeds)
for employeefirstname
IN (' + @pet + ')
) as p'
```

Comment: Show where you were using isnull.

Comment: You should just be able to add it into the select on the specific columns, like @AnthonyHorne said show the query where you have used them

Comment: Try select statement As like  SELECT ISNULL(employeefirstname,''0'') AS employeefirstname, ISNULL(breeds,''0'') As breeds,     ISNULL([Month],''0'') As [Month] FROM

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNULL() in the outermost SELECT.  In your case, the one after `SELECT * FROM (`

If that doesn't work, then replace the `SELECT *` with `SELECT ISNULL(column1) etc...`